# ClassNotFoundException using ClassLoader in a FileWalker

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception

I have a program where the User selects a Directory to begin a FileWalk from; the FileWalker visits each file in the directory structure loading `.class` files with a `CLassLoader` so I can use `Reflection` on them to display information about that class in a GUI.

If the user selects the folder FileReader which has this strucuture:

```
D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader
    │
    ├───+bin
    │   │   ReadFile.class   
    |
    │
    └───+src
        │   ReadFile.java
```

The `ClassLoader` has no problem loading `ReadFile.class`

However if I select the same directory with an added class in the package Test:

```
D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader
    │
    ├───+bin
    │   │   ReadFile.class
    │   │
    │   └───+Test
    │           TestClass.class
    │
    └───+src
        │   ReadFile.java
        │
        └───+Test
                TestClass.java
```

Eclipse throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.TestClass`.

So why am I getting a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`? Below is my code with some `System.out.println()` to show some values as it goes through. (The directory structure is the same as the strucuture above)

```
public class ReflectOnClasses extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    //Starts the file walk from a starting directory
    public static void startFileWalk(String directory){

        //The startingDir is the directory the user selects on the Main UI Part
        Path startingDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(directory, "");
        System.out.println("Staring Directory the user selected: " + startingDir);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        //Create an instance of my FileVisitor
        ReflectOnClasses reflectOnClasses = new ReflectOnClasses();

        try {
            //Walk the files from my startingDir using reflectOnClasses
            Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, reflectOnClasses);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("An Error Occured");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Visit files and do something with them
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path filesPath, BasicFileAttributes attr) {

        //If we find a .class file get it and reflect upon it
        if(filesPath.toString().endsWith(".class")){

            //Create a File object of the files directory
            File parentDir = new File(filesPath.getParent().toString());
            System.out.println("Parent Directory: " + filesPath.getParent().toString());

            try{

                //Convert parentDir to URL
                URL url = parentDir.toURL();
                URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

                //Create a new class loader with the directory
                ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

                /*
                 * To load a class we need the class name and the package it belongs too in the format
                 * "example.package.name\FooBar". We can easily get the class name by getting the name
                 * of filesPath and removing the .class on the end
                 */
                String className = filesPath.getFileName().toString().replace(".class", "");
                System.out.println("The className: " + className);

                //classesPackage + className
                String classToLoad = getPackageName(filesPath) + className;
                System.out.println("The classToLoad: " + classToLoad);


                //Load in the class
                Class<?> cls = cl.loadClass(classToLoad);

                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");

                //Pass the name of the class to addClassToVariableTree in CreatUI so it can be added as a TreeItem
                CreateMainUI.addClassToVariableTree(classToLoad);
                //Do the same for addClassToMethodTree
                CreateMainUI.addClassToMethodTree(classToLoad);

                //Array of the declared fields in the class
                Field[] fieldsInClass = cls.getDeclaredFields();

                //For each field in fieldsInClass we add it as a TreeItem using addVariableToClassTreeItem
                for( Field field: fieldsInClass){
                    CreateMainUI.addVariableToClassNameTreeItem(field.getGenericType().toString(), field.getName());
                }

                //Array of all methods in the class
                Method[] methodsInClass = cls.getDeclaredMethods();

                //For each method we pass through the string representation of it, the class it belongs too and it's name. It will be formatted in CreateUI
                for (Method method : methodsInClass) {
                    CreateMainUI.addMethodToClassNameTreeItem(method.toString(), classToLoad, method.getName());
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("URL BAD");
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("Class couldnt be found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return CONTINUE;

    }

    private String getPackageName(Path filesPath){

        /*
         * To get the package name we will have to construct it manually. If the class
         * was already loaded we could get the package info using built in Java methods, but we
         * haven't loaded the class yet and can't without this package information hence we will
         * build a package name up be traversing back up to the bin folder adding the folder titles
         * to a String Builder as we go
         */
        File currentFolder = filesPath.toFile().getParentFile();

        String classesPackage = "";

        while(true){

            if(!(currentFolder.getName().equals("bin"))){

                classesPackage = currentFolder.getName() + "." + classesPackage;

                currentFolder = currentFolder.getParentFile();
            }
            else{

                break;
            }
        }

        return classesPackage;
    }

}
```

Console output:

```
Staring Directory the user selected: D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader
----------------------------------------------------
Parent Directory: D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader\bin
The className: ReadFile
The classToLoad: ReadFile
--------------------------------------------------------
Parent Directory: D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader\bin\Test
The className: TestClass
The classToLoad: Test.TestClass
Class couldnt be found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.TestClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at ste.wootten.honoursproject.mainpart.reflection.ReflectOnClasses.visitFile(ReflectOnClasses.java:146)
    at ste.wootten.honoursproject.mainpart.reflection.ReflectOnClasses.visitFile(ReflectOnClasses.java:1)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:135)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:199)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:199)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:199)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2591)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2624)
    at ste.wootten.honoursproject.mainpart.reflection.ReflectOnClasses.startFileWalk(ReflectOnClasses.java:41)
    at ste.wootten.honoursproject.mainpart.CreateMainUI.selectDirectoryAndBeginFileWalk(CreateMainUI.java:258)
    at ste.wootten.honoursproject.mainpart.CreateMainUI.createInterface(CreateMainUI.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

As you can see it finds `ReadFile.class` and loads that fine, but when I want to load `Test.TestClass` it says `ClassNotFoundException`. Any ideas??

Comment: Is TestClass in the package Test? Check the file URL and be sure it matches the package of the class.

Comment: Yes TestClass is in the package Test. I printed out the file url which gave file:/D:/Users/Ste/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Project Tests/File Reader/bin/Test/ that seems right doesn't it?

Comment: Print out your URLs as part of your debugging. I'm guessing that your URL is the directory where the class resides, while it should be the root of the tree.

Comment: @parsifal Could you give an example of what you mean? If TestClass.class is in D:/Users/Ste/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Project Tests/File Reader/bin/Test/ what should the URL be?

Comment: Assuming that it's really `Test.TestClass` (as in your example), the root of the classpath should be `D:/Users/Ste/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Project Tests/File Reader/bin/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you walk `TestFile.class`

```
File parentDir = new File(filesPath.getParent().toString());
System.out.println("Parent Directory: " + filesPath.getParent().toString());
```

After this, you have `parentDir = "D:\Users\Ste\Documents\Eclipse Workspace\Project Tests\File Reader\bin\Test"`

```
URL url = parentDir.toURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
//Create a new class loader with the directory
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

After this, you have your class loader search directory to be `file:///D:/Users/Ste.../bin/Test` which is not correct (there's no `/Test/TestClass.class` from here to match the compiled `Test.TestClass`)

In this case, you should create your class loader from `startingDir + "/bin"` and not from `parentDir`.

Here is a very basic [Java Package Tutorial](http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html) in case you need help to understand what is happening.